# How to interpret boundary noise?

Tags: stochastic-analysis, boundary-value-problem, stochastic-differential-equations

Currently, I am writing on my Master Thesis about stochastic Equations with boundary noise.
Based on the same-named [paper by M.Veerar and R.Schaubelt](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-0075-4_30).

My question is less contentual and more about the basic idea behind a noise on the boundary. Inner noise is a bit more understandable for me, for example the stochastic Navier-Stokes Equations. Here, the stochastic term represents outer perturbations which influences the flow of the fluid and the stochastic fluctuation of the particles.

Is there also a good example for stochastic terms on the boundary, which makes this a bit more clear? Since I don't found much literature about this topic maybe someone can give me a picturesque description. :) If there is some literature I didn't see, this would also help me out a lot.
I Am just interested in understanding the background of this topic a bit more.